# Jpa Update tables get Null

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm kind a new in programming and I'm trying to update tables with requestDto that have multiple entities with one request. Each tables mapped by Invoice tables, has Foreign Keys But I got Null from other tables when I PUT update.

```
This is Service, I only put Invoice and Seller but get null from Seller
@Transactional
    public Long update(Long id, InvoiceUpdateRequestDto requestDto){

        Invoice invoice = invoiceRepository.getOne(id);
        invoice.update(requestDto.getNote(), requestDto.getSeller());
        Seller seller = new Seller();
        seller.setSellerManagerNumber(requestDto.getSeller().getSellerManagerNumber());
        sellerRepository.save(seller);
    return id;
    }
```

I made inner Dto,

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class InvoiceUpdateRequestDto {

    private String note;
    private boolean finalized;
    private DeliveryUpdateRequest delivery;
    private ProductUpdateRequest product;
    private BuyerUpdateRequest buyer;
    private SellerUpdateRequest seller;

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class DeliveryUpdateRequest  {
        private String destination;
        private String address;
    }
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class ProductUpdateRequest {
        private String productNumber;
        private String productName;
        private int stockQuantity;
    }
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class BuyerUpdateRequest  {
        private String companyName;
        private String buyerManager;
        private String buyerManagerNumber;
        private String faxNumber;
    }
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class SellerUpdateRequest  {
        private String companyName;
        private String sellerManager;
        private String sellerManagerNumber;
        private String faxNumber;
    }
```

this is invoice entity

```
@Getter
@Entity
public class Invoice extends BaseEntity {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "invoice_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "buyer_id")
    private Buyer buyer;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "seller_id")
    private Seller seller;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "delivery_id")
    private Delivery delivery;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "orderItem_id")
    private OrderItem orderItem;

    private boolean finalized;

    public boolean isFinalized() {
        return finalized;
    }
    public Invoice(){
    }
    private String note;


//I put only Seller for now to test it.
public void update(String note, Seller seller){
        this.note= note;
        this.seller = seller;
    }
```

this is controller

```
@PutMapping("/api/order/{id}/update") //
    public ResponseEntity<HashMap<String, String>> updateInvoice(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody InvoiceUpdateRequestDto requestDto) {
        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("message", "Success");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(invoiceService.update(id,requestDto)).status(HttpStatus.OK).body(result); }
```

I think I made a mistake in Service. Could you tell me what I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to save `SellerUpdateRequest` into the invoice entity. Create Seller out of the request and set it in invoice. And I don't think you are saving the invoice after updating the entity, You try this:

```
@Transactional
public Long update(Long id, InvoiceUpdateRequestDto requestDto){
    Seller seller = new Seller();
    seller.setSellerManagerNumber(requestDto.getSeller().getSellerManagerNumber());
    // save rest of the fields of seller
    sellerRepository.save(seller); 
    Invoice invoice = invoiceRepository.getOne(id);
    invoice.update(requestDto.getNote(), seller);
    invoiceRepository.save(invoice);  // save the invoice here
    return id;
}
```

Comment: I keep getting Null for All Seller tables. if I put ManagerNumber there it becomes Null even other tables as well.

Comment: Did you try with the suggested code? You were trying to save DTO into entity. Now you need to create a new Seller entity with the fields from DTO and then save it to the invoice. Are you getting null even after these changes?

Comment: invoiceRepository.save(id) <- I got inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; error, Did you mean invoiceRepository.save(invoice)?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Updated the answer

Comment: but it doesn't work :( , it keep getting null for all tables in Seller.

Comment: Can you manually try to save the seller before and then add the seller as shown in the updated code? Can you also check in share what sqls statements are being executed in the logs?